# access 2010 accdb file bloating when i copy attachment field?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, dao

A table which has around 300 records with a photo attachment field, I need to copy those 300 records to another table.

So the below function which will call 300 times.

```
Private Sub copyAttachmentField(ByRef srcField As DAO.Field, ByRef expField As DAO.Field)
    On Error GoTo Err_copyAttachmentField
    Dim rsSrcAtt As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsExpAtt As DAO.Recordset

    Set rsSrcAtt = srcField.Value
    Set rsExpAtt = expField.Value

    If Not (rsSrcAtt.BOF And rsSrcAtt.EOF) Then
        rsSrcAtt.MoveFirst
        Do While Not rsSrcAtt.EOF
            rsExpAtt.AddNew
            rsExpAtt.fields("filedata").Value = rsSrcAtt.fields("filedata").Value   <==== THIS I REMARK IT TO DEBUG
            rsExpAtt.fields("filename").Value = rsSrcAtt.fields("filename").Value
            rsExpAtt.Update
            rsSrcAtt.MoveNext
        Loop
    End If

    rsSrcAtt.Close
    rsExpAtt.Close
    Set rsSrcAtt = Nothing
    Set rsExpAtt = Nothing

    Exit Sub

Err_copyAttachmentField:
    If Err.Number = 3420 Then
        rsSrcAtt.Close
        rsExpAtt.Close
        Set rsSrcAtt = Nothing
        Set rsExpAtt = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description
        Resume
    End If
End Sub
```

Every time, the accdb grow 100M Bytes. I can sure that the photo is very small. they are just 50k jpg file. So 300 * 50k = 15,000k only. (15MB)

Then I remark the "filedata" line, it will not grow again...

Comment: Have you tried copying the records with a SQL INSERT statement (or Append query) instead of VBA? Don't know if it would make a difference, but all this code seems a bit unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, your suggestions is make sense. Sql is the most effective and direct way to moving records. I have try it before, the access sql engine cannot copy attachment field.(>﹏<). It just leave it blank. You can try if you have access 2007-2010. 2013 I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to do about it other than running a compact afterwards.

It doesn't hurt or damage anything, though, but if you can't live with it, you will have to save your attachments as external separate files.

Comment: I have try what you say for a whole day already~>_<~.  I have also try to split it into ui and database. It show the same bloat. And I also has try compact and repair, the size does not sink! Now I have to new a accdb, and import the tables again.

Comment: OK, I thought you deleted the attachments after the copy. If not, the db will, of course, grow in size. The large increment may be because Access converts and stores the attachments as bitmaps much larger than the jgps.

Comment: *"Access converts and stores the attachments as bitmaps much larger than the jgps"* - not true, for `Attachment` fields at least. Back in the days of OLE embedded images there was a huge amount of bloat when saving images in Office documents. However, an `Attachment` field in Access can store virtually *any* type of file (not just images) in that file's native format. In fact, Access will actually *compress* certain types of files when saving them as an attachment.

Comment: OK, but that seems not to be the case here.

Comment: I guess the database bloat is cause by some temporary object not released during dao vba operation. But cannot be free by compact database.